# Why can't composer find a composer.json file inside my Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a pretty straightforward Dockerfile based on [Thelia's](https://github.com/thelia/thelia/blob/master/docker/php/Dockerfile) and [Composer's](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/%7E/dockerfile/). I want it to do as much setup as possible, so to that end, I am installing `composer` in the `PATH` within the container and then trying to run `composer install`. However, at that point, it seems my local/mounted files don't exist within the container yet (see output from `RUN echo pwd: ...` below).

The build fails with this error message:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
>
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
>
> ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c composer install' returned a non-zero code: 1

**Note that building without the `RUN composer install` instruction and then running `docker-compose exec web composer install` works.**

Does the mount declared in docker-compose.yml not take effect until the image has been completely built? Do I need to explicitly `COPY` my local files for them to be visible during the build process?

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY docker-php-pecl-install /usr/local/bin/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
 libfreetype6-dev \
 libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
 libmcrypt-dev \
 libpng12-dev \
 libicu-dev \
 git \
 zip \
 libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo_mysql mcrypt mbstring zip calendar \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-pecl-install xdebug-2.3.3

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY config/vhost/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

# Expose webroot
VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html # Added at Edit 1

# Allow Composer to be run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

# Setup the Composer installer
RUN curl -o /tmp/composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  && curl -o /tmp/composer-setup.sig https://composer.github.io/installer.sig \
  && php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.php')) !== trim(file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.sig'))) { unlink('/tmp/composer-setup.php'); echo 'Invalid installer' . PHP_EOL; exit(1); }" \
  && php /tmp/composer-setup.php \
  && chmod a+x composer.phar \
  && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install composer dependencies
RUN echo pwd: `pwd` && echo ls: `ls`  # outputs:
                                      # pwd: /var/www/html
                                      # ls:
RUN composer install
```

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  build: ./docker/php
  ports:
    - "8002:80"
  links:
    - mariaDB
  environment:
    SYMFONY_ENV: dev
  command: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html

mariaDB:
   ...
```

### Edit 1 - after `COPY`ing files explicitly

I added a `COPY . /var/www/html` after the `VOLUME` and `WORKDIR` instructions, and noticed something weird. Now the `RUN pwd: ...` instruction echoes:

> pwd: /var/www/html
>
> ls: Dockerfile config docker-php-pecl-install

This is the contents of my docker/php directory, not the project root!

Full(ish) directory structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Readme.md
├── Thelia
├── bin
│   └── ...
├── bootstrap.php
├── cache
│   └── ...
├── change-version.sh
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── docker
│   └── php
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── config
│       └── docker-php-pecl-install
├── docker-compose.yml
├── lib
│   └── Thelia
│       └── Project
├── local
│   └── ...
├── log
├── templates
│   └── ...
├── vendor
│   └── ...
└── web
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── index.php
    ├── index_dev.php
    └── robots.txt
```

So my revised question is: **how do I tell Docker to `COPY` from the context in which I run `docker-compose`?** I thought this was the default behavior for `docker-compose`, and that's how it's worked for me on past projects...

Comment: Try with: `RUN  /usr/local/bin/composer install`

Comment: It's either that or you haven't copied your local files inside the docker scope. You set the workdir, but I don't see you copying the relevant files there.

Comment: @k0pernikus, specifying the absolute path to `composer` gives the same error. I added a `COPY` instruction and noticed something weird...see edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define a docker-compose 1.7 file with:

```
web:
  build: ./docker/php
```

which results basically in:

```
docker build -f ./docker/php/Dockerfile ./docker/php/
```

So basically the build path *is* the context of the build process.

If you really want to define the context, you have to upgrade your docker-compose defintion to at least [v2 or v3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

There you should be able to do:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
```

I would advise against that as:

- whenever one edits that Dockerfile, you always have to remember the parent's folder context structure, which will be quite hard to maintain
- as the context grows ever larger, you will slow the build process by sending a huge amount of data into the container build's context. A `.dockerignore` file would help, but you would have to use it as a whitelist instead of a blacklist.

---

If you want to build multiple php containers that all install dependencies with your `docker-php-pecl-install` file, I advise you to not inject a god context, but that your rather create a base php image from its own Dockerfile, which you then reference in the in the other's containers Dockerfile as the `FROM` source. That base image can be an unrelated project, all you need it do to is built an image,  and reused in different other php projects.

If you want to reuse that image in your entire company, it's helpful to setup a private docker registry, where you and your team can push and pull images from.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, when you say "remember the parent's folder context structure," you mean something like having something like `COPY ./docker/php/docker-php-pecl-install /usr/local/bin/` specifying a project-relative path inside the Dockerfile?

Comment: @acobster I mean when you change the context, whenever you edit the `Dockerfile` you won't know right away know what `./` refers to. If context equals build path, it's easy: context will be where also the Dockerfile lives. If someelse wants to use your Dockerfile as a starting point, they have to remap your custom context to theirs. It's just painful. (I have been there.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, even in the course of experimenting with the "god context" you recommend against, I shot myself in the foot. :) Since this is just for a proof-of-concept for now, I'm going to go with the band-aid solution. But if this ever becomes a Dockerfile I expect others to consume, I will definitely create a base image that just abstracts away the pecl-install script. Thanks!